# Percentage of variable corresponding to percentage of other variable

Tags: conditional-statements, qliksense, cumsum

I have two numerical variables, and would like to calculate the percentage of one variable corresponding to at least 50% of the other variable's sum.

***For example***:

```
A   |   B
__________
2   |   8
1   |  20
3   |  12
5   |   4
2   |   7
1   |  11
4   |   5
```

Here, the sum of column B is `68`, so I'm looking for the rows (in B's descending order) where cumulative sum is at least `34`.

In that case, they are rows 2, 3 & 6 (cumulative sum of `45`). The sum of these row's column A is `5`, which I want to compare to the total sum of column A (`18`).

Therefore, the result I'm looking for is `5 / 18 * 100 =` **28.78%**

I'm looking for a way to implement this in QlikSense, or in SQL.

Comment: Hi - where does the `18` come from in your final sum? I can't find where that comes from in your data. I'll put most of an answer below and update when you can explain that.

Comment: I edited the question. `18` is the sum of column A.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it - there is probably some optimisation to be done, but this gives what you want.

```
Source: 
LOAD 
    *,
    RowNo() as RowNo_Source
Inline [
A , B
2 , 8
1 , 20
3 , 12
5 , 4
2 , 7
1 , 11
4 , 5
];

SourceSorted:
NoConcatenate LOAD *,
    RowNo() as RowNo_SourceSorted
Resident Source
Order by B asc;

drop table Source;

BTotal:
LOAD sum(B) as BTotal
Resident SourceSorted;

let BTotal=peek('BTotal',0);

SourceWithCumu:
NoConcatenate LOAD
    *,
    rangesum(peek('BCumu'),B) as BCumu,
    $(BTotal) as BTotal,
    rangesum(peek('BCumu'),B)/$(BTotal) as BCumuPct,
    if(rangesum(peek('BCumu'),B)/$(BTotal)>=0.5,A,0) as AFiltered
Resident SourceSorted;

Drop Table SourceSorted;
```

I worked with a debug fields that might be useful but you could of course remove these.

Then in the front end you do your calculation of `sum(AFiltered)/sum(A)` to get the stat you want and format it as a percentage.

Comment: Thanks! It sure is a long way there! 

I was more thinking of creating a custom measure, so that the values can be dynamically changed with filter on other variables.